# Disable subword-mode for some languages in Prelude

Tags: prelude, subword-mode

I have found `subword-mode` to interfere negatively with my flow, specially when using [`drag-stuff`](https://github.com/rejeep/drag-stuff.el), and I'd like to disable it, if not globally, at least for a couple of languages.

I have tried `(subword-mode 0)` in my `custom.el` file and it didn't work. I thought about editing other modes manually, and the idea doesn't seem to scale with updates etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Prelude, so maybe this won't be helpful, but `subword-mode` is buffer-local, so if it seems to be active everywhere Prelude is probably using `global-subword-mode` instead.  So try

```
(global-subword-mode -1)
```

in your `~/.emacs`.  You can also try and turn it off selectively in some modes with lines like

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (subword-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (subword-mode -1)))
```

Comment: Interesting.  It seems `global-subword-mode` is not mentionned in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MixedCase-Words.html#MixedCase-Words), I suggest it should be.  Also, `global-subword-mode` docstring links to `subword-mode` but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Sadly neither of the options worked.

Comment: Note it also works for `whitespace-mode`, `auto-fill-mode`, etc.